# How to stop redirecting our Salesforce users clicking on an a URL for an activity record to an account record

Tags: lightning, account, url, activity, external-app

I'm building an internal interface for day-to-day work processes on a platform outside of Salesforce that uses data from our Salesforce.

I've created a button on that external platform that should take users, if logged in to Salesforce, to an activity (i,e. logged email) using a formula that plugs in the activity record ID into the following URL:

**domain.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/EmailMessage/ACTIVITY-RECORD-ID/view**

However, when one clicks on the URL, Salesforce automatically redirects to the account that is linked to that activity. The URL changes to something like this:

**domain.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Account/ACCOUNT-RECORD-ID/view**

Is there a setting we have turned on that makes it do this, and how do I turn it off?

Comment: Maybe try this: *domain.lightning.force.com/ACTIVITY-RECORD-ID*

Comment: does the user have `Access Activities` permission? Does your Org Wide Defaults in Sharing Settings have activity viz as Controlled By Parent or Private?